Can applications copy files from one docker volume to another?
I have a docker application that uses a composer container to download dependencies and copy over public resources from them. The container should copy files from the vendor directory to the public/_resources directory. The vendor directory exists within a volume, but other files under /public are on the host machine.
Can an application's code copy files from one volume to another?
I suppose this could also work by copying directly to the host machine, but currently, neither solution seems to work.
With this docker-compose.yml file, I am left with an empty public/_resources/vendor directory. No error shows in the composer container's logs.
services:
  php:
    image: silverstripe-php:8.1
    build:
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/php.dockerfile
    hostname: localhost
    volumes:
      - ./public:/var/www/html/public
      - ss-vendor-resources:/var/www/html/public/_resources/vendor
      - ./themes:/var/www/html/themes:cached
      - ss-vendor:/var/www/html/vendor
      - ./composer.json:/var/www/html/composer.json

  composer:
    image: composer/composer
    volumes:
      - ./public:/var/www/html/public:cached
      - ss-vendor:/var/www/html/vendor
      - ss-vendor-resources:/var/www/html/public/_resources/vendor
      - ./composer.json:/var/www/html/composer.json
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    command: update
    environment:
      SS_VENDOR_METHOD: copy

volumes:
  ss-vendor:
  ss-vendor-resources:


"Volumes" in a container are just directories...the question "can an application copy files from one volume to another?" is really the same thing as asking "can an application copy files?". (The answer, of course, is "yes", as long as you have set the permissions correctly.)

Can you run Composer within your application's Dockerfile, instead of trying to run it as a separate container?  And then delete all of the volumes:, which will hide the code built into your image?

I strongly recommend checking out DDEV which will take care of the dockerfile for you so you can focus on development. Yes you can do what you're asking about. No it's probably not worth your time fiddling with unless your job requires you to know how to set up docker environments from scratch.

"Neither solution seems to work" isn't all that useful when we aren't given enough details to see or say what goes wrong. Without knowing what your update command does, why should we expect it to do any copy operations at all?

@CharlesDuffy I linked the composer vendor plugin that performs the copy.
